# How to clean up this jQuery snippet correctly

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jQuery snippet to change the background position of a image, when the links are hovered. But I have to add alot more selectors to it, and it's going to take up alot of lines this way, but I cannot seem to find a way to minify it? Can it be done? Or maby there is a more correct way to do this background changing?

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
jQuery(".1-panel").hover(function(){
    jQuery(".panel-image").css('background-position','0px -135px');
});
jQuery(".2-panel").hover(function(){
    jQuery(".panel-image").css('background-position','0px 0px');
});
jQuery(".3-panel").hover(function(){
    jQuery(".panel-image").css('background-position','0px -265px');
});
jQuery(".4-panel").hover(function(){
    jQuery(".panel-image").css('background-position','0px -560px');
});
jQuery(".5-panel").hover(function(){
    jQuery(".panel-image").css('background-position','0px -410px');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you share the relevant html as well

Comment: yes exactly, was "minifying" just came to mind first, I'm actually seeking to clean up the code yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll add a common class like `panel` to all the 5 elements `1-panel, .... 5-panel`, also add an additional data-* attribute like `data-imagebp` like

```
<div class="1-panel panel" data-imagebp="0px -135px">...</div>
<div class="2-panel panel" data-imagebp="0px 0px">...</div>
...
<div class="5-panel panel" data-imagebp="0px -410px">...</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $pimage = $(".panel-image");
    $(".panel").mouseenter(function () {
        $pimage.css('background-position', $(this).data('imagebp'));
    });
});
```

Note: There is no need to use hover() here as you are not doing anything in mouse leave event, so you can just register the mouseenter handler